# PHPUnit says route not defined (Laravel)

Tags: php, laravel, unit-testing, laravel-5, phpunit

I run a unit-test on routing. Funny thing is: PHPUnit says "all good" for the **first test in a test file**, but fails with **"route not defined"** for **exactly** the same test if it only goes **second** in the file.

I tried to create dummy test with only

```
$this->assertTrue(true);
```

and put is as a first test, the second test doing some work, precisely:

```
$this->call('GET', "http:....."); 
$this->assertRedirectedToRoute('login');
```

and it fails.

But this same test gives me success if it goes first in the file. Very strange.

Does anyone know why is it happening?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I solved the case. It was routing. In my `\app\Http\routes.php` file I had inclusions.

The fix was changing `require_once` to `require` in my `routes.php` file.

Comment: Please, if this answer is working for you, mention your laravel version.

Comment: Thanks, this answer helped me out.

Comment: This helped me in Laravel 5.x. Note that the default is not a single `routes.php` file but a `web.php` and `api.php` (referenced in [RouteServiceProvider.php](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/app/Providers/RouteServiceProvider.php)) so and there we iterate over globbed other route files to `require_once $routeFile`. Made a conditional so it will `require $routeFile` during testing.

Comment: Thanks, it worked, but - do you have any Idea why? I don't. Laravel 6.2.

Comment: I'm having the same exact issue with laravel 8.83.27. but i can't find any use of require_once in route files so this solution doesn't work for me...